# How do I wait for both Cordova and jQuery to load their libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, dom-events

jQuery has the "ready" function:

```
$(function() {...});
```

and the cordova documentation says to add an event listener:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false();
function onDeviceReady(){...}
```

**Do I need to call both of these to make sure both the libraries are loaded before any code that references them is used?**

Does it make sense to nest them, i.e.:

```
$(function(){
    onDeviceReady(){...}
}
```

Just trying to figure out the best way to do this, maybe I am overthinking it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JS files are loaded sequentially. So in your HTML just put your .js file after jQuery and cordova and it won't run before both are loaded.

```
<script src="jQuery"></script>
<script src="cordova"></script>
<script src="yourScript"></script> <!-- this won't run before both jQ and cordova are loaded -->
```

As for ready events, if you don't want to nest them, you could construct your own event for when all the libraries are ready:

```
var listener = {
    jquery: false,
    cordova: false,
    fire: function(e) {listener[e] = true; if (listener.jquery && listener.cordova) go();
};
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){listener.fire('cordova'), false();
$(document).ready(function(listener.fire('jquery')){});

function go() {
// your code here
}
```

This will work, and go() will fire when all are loaded, however I'm really not sure if you actually need all of this and is there a simper way to do it.

Comment: You were probably downvoted because although you are correct, the problem is that jQuery and cordova both fire "I'm ready" type of events when the libraries are fully loaded and initialized, and I think that the order these events get fired is not necessarily the same as the order that their script tags appear (for example if the first script does a ton of ajax requests.) Although, not positive.

Comment: Updated my answer with a listener that checks for ready events.

Comment: I'd assume that OP needs to listen for both event listeners to fire but I'm not sure, which is why I haven't answered...but your expanded answer looks good to me. I think it makes sense to listen to both listeners.

Comment: yeah, i believe I need to listen for both event listeners because I am using jQuery to listen for a `click` event that will call `cordova.exec` to communicate with my plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Put document.ready inside deviceready:

```
var onDeviceReady = function (){
    jQuery(document).ready(function (){
        // go!
    });
};

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

jQuery's [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is a proxy for [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) and signifies that the document is parsed and can safely be queried or manipulated.

jQuery itself (`jQuery`, `$`) is available as soon as the library has finished executing; you don't need to do anything special to wait for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your jquery functions after the deviceready .Let me give you a full example of how you can do this.
First ensure you have added the needed cordova/phonegap plugin that youre going to use.In my case I have loaded the device plugin.

Open a blank document add the html skeleton then in the head part of your html,add the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>//include the cordova.js file
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>//include the jquery.min.js file strictly after the cordova.js file
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {

        $(document).ready(function(){ //jquery starts here and is inside the device ready function


            //the next few lines are now the calling my plugins
            //#deviceproperties is a paragraph in html that has an id deviceproperties
            //#hideme is a span inside the paragaraph that has the id deviceproperties.inside the span is the statement that is saying 'loading device properties' and will be removed as soon as the script hide() runs

           $('#deviceProperties').prepend("<br>" + device.cordova 
                                 + "<br>" + device.platform
                                 + "<br>" + device.uuid
                                 + "<br>" + device.version
                                  );

            $('#hideme').hide();//hide the loading device properties
        });//lets end jquery`s document.ready

    }//lets end cordova`s device ready

</script>
```

Loading device properties...